# Need Excel VBA to copy columm B, C, D... to the column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem that I need your help. I need code VBA to copy column B,C...
to the column A, attached image. Can someone give me a solution?

[image]

Comment: You can record a macro while doing this action manually with selecting the `B1` cell, jumping down the entire range by pressing `shift+ctrl+(down)`, cutting, jumping down to the last record in the `A` column and pasting. Then open the macro and parameterize the code to also work for other columns, to check if any first row in a column holds data, etc...

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow will not write code for you from scratch; show that you've done some preliminary work and ask about a specific point where the code fails. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the SO-format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to achieve it:

```
Sub Collate()
Dim Pos As Long, Col As Integer, TotCols As Integer

TotCols = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

For Col = 2 To TotCols
    Pos = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 'To get the last available row
    Range(Cells(1, Col), Cells(1, Col).End(xlDown)).Copy Range("A" & Pos)

    'To remove data from columns
    Range(Cells(1, Col), Cells(1, Col).End(xlDown)).Clear
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following code:

```
Sub consolidateColumns()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long

With ActiveSheet 'Replace with the worksheet you need, avoid using ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To 3 'Adjust the 3 to however many columns you need
        lr2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lr2, i)).Cut .Cells(lr + 1, 1)
        lr = lr + lr2
    Next i
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

To make it shorter, but harder to read at first you could also use the following code:

```
Sub consolidateColumns()

With ActiveSheet 'Replace with the worksheet you need, avoid using ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To 3 'Adjust the 3 to however many columns you need
        .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i)).Cut .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
    Next i
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```